# How to test if a tree item is the root node for the treeview in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-errors, treeview

I have been trying to prevent my program from deleting the root node of my tree view but when ever I try and do so my program gives me a "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" during its compiling and the program will not launch. I am not really sure why it will not launch.

Here is my TextFieldTreeCellImpl class where the error takes place:

```
private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {

    private TextField textField;
    private ContextMenu addMenu = new ContextMenu();


    public TextFieldTreeCellImpl() {
        MenuItem addMenuItem0 = new MenuItem("Add Folder");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem0);
        addMenuItem0.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                TreeItem<String> newFolder = 
                    new TreeItem<String>("New Folder",new ImageView(depIcon));
                        getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newFolder);
            }
        });

        MenuItem addMenuItem1 = new MenuItem("Delete");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem1);

        addMenuItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {//There is not error when the if statement is in here
                        getTreeItem().getParent().getChildren().remove(getTreeItem());
                }
        });
        if(getTreeItem().getParent()==null){//The error is here-------------
             addMenuItem1.disableProperty().set(true);
        }
    }

    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null) {
            createTextField();
        }
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
    }


    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    setContextMenu(addMenu);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });  

    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.CopyOfMain$TextFieldTreeCellImpl.<init>(CopyOfMain.java:82)
at application.CopyOfMain$1.call(CopyOfMain.java:48)
at application.CopyOfMain$1.call(CopyOfMain.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeViewSkin.createCell(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeViewSkin.lambda$new$513(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeViewSkin$$Lambda$115/979660402.call(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
at application.CopyOfMain.start(CopyOfMain.java:54)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$57/1520696636.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1933975749.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Exception running application application.CopyOfMain
```

And here is my Main Class although I do not think that it is realavent:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private final Node rootIcon = 
    new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder.jpg")));
private final Image depIcon = 
    new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder.jpg"));

TreeItem<String> rootNode = 
    new TreeItem<String>("Resources", rootIcon);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage stage) {
    rootNode.setExpanded(true); 
    stage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
    VBox box = new VBox();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 300);
    scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(rootNode);
    treeView.setEditable(true);
    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>,TreeCell<String>>(){
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
            return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();
        }
    });

    box.getChildren().add(treeView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

One thing that I did notice is that if I put the if statment in one of the handle methods there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time that the `TextFieldTreeCellImpl` object is constructed, there isn't a `TreeItem` associated to it. That typically happens shortly after construction and outside of your control. Regardless, the call to `getTreeItem()` is returning `null` and so the chained called to `getParent()` is then causing the NPE. The reason it works when you move it inside the handler is because that code is only called when an event is triggered (i.e. clicking on `addMenuItem1`) and by that time, the `treeItem` is populated in the cell.

I would add another `EventHandler` for the `onShowing` event of the `ContextMenu` and put the check and set inside of there. See the example in the docs: [ContextMenu Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html)